# What's the difference between Converter and HandlerMethodArgumentResolver?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, type-conversion

In Spring MVC, I can use `PropertyEditor`(`Converter`) or `WebArgumentResolver`(`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`) to make customized command and form-backing objects. I'm puzzled which one should I use and what's the difference between them? Thanks a lot!

p.s. I know `Converter` and `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` is recommended now. I've read the posts below:

[Spring MVC type conversion : PropertyEditor or Converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544479/spring-mvc-type-conversion-propertyeditor-or-converter)

[Upgrading to spring-3.1 seems to break my CustomWebArgumentResolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357817/upgrading-to-spring-3-1-seems-to-break-my-customwebargumentresolver)

Comment: ConversionService in Spring http://http://stackoverflow.com/a/4348708/2218838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A converter simply converts between two different types. An `HttpMessageConverter` converts a request message having a defined media type to an instance of a defined class. Converters are usually called by argument resolvers.

An argument resolver provides a value for an argument. E.g. there is a resolver that creates the value based an a request parameter (`@RequestParam`) or one that converts the request body (`@RequestBody`). Both use converters.

But the value doesn't have to be related to the request. You could create a resolver that returns the current time, something like

```
public void foo(@CurrentTime Date) {
```